# Unable to attach Event to an Submit button in a form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

On the following page "https://www.capgemini.com/new-ways-to-accelerate-innovation". there are multiple sections with "Expand" button and when you click on expand button a form gets exposed. the issue here is am not able to attach click event to the "Submit" button.

I have tried using `addeventlistener` but the event is not getting assigned.

How do I do that, please advise.

https://www.capgemini.com/new-ways-to-accelerate-innovation

**Expand Button is in the below code.**

```
<div class="exp_article-header-bg">
  <div class="exp_article-header-inner">
    <h2 class="exp_article-header-title">TechnoVision 2017</h2>
    <div class="exp_article-header-author"></div>
    <div class="exp_article-header-lead">
      <p>
      TechnoVision 2017 gives you a framework to create a new digital story to solve problems and grasp new opportunities. Our 37 technology building blocks will help you to navigate the technology maze and give a clear direction to your business.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="exp_article-header-expand">
      **
      <div class="exp_link exp_link--white exp_link--expand">
        <span class="exp_link-label">EXPAND</span>**
        <span class="exp_button-arrow exp_button-arrow--down"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Form gets exposed when you click the above Expand button. The Submit button is in the form as highlighted below.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" action="https://go.pardot.com/l/95412/2017-08-09/2tfbfg" class="form" id="pardot-form">
    <style type="text/css">
      form.form p label {
        color: #000000;
      }
    </style>

    <p class="form-field  email pd-text required    ">
      <label class="field-label" for="95412_59459pi_95412_59459">Email Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="95412_59459pi_95412_59459" id="95412_59459pi_95412_59459" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="255" onchange="piAjax.auditEmailField(this, 95412, 59459, 44072473);">
    </p>
    <div id="error_for_95412_59459pi_95412_59459" style="display:none"></div>
    <p style="position:absolute; width:190px; left:-9999px; top: -9999px;visibility:hidden;">
      <label for="pi_extra_field">Comments</label>
      <input type="text" name="pi_extra_field" id="pi_extra_field">
    </p>

    <!-- forces IE5-8 to correctly submit UTF8 content  -->
    <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="☃">

    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Submit Now">
    </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        if (anchor.getAttribute("href") && !anchor.getAttribute("target")) {
          anchor.target = "_top";
        }
      }
      //]]>
    </script>
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenDependentFields" id="hiddenDependentFields" value="">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have CSS display:none; for the element which needs to be expanded. when expand is clicked call a javascript function which checks if the element is hidden , if hidden change the CSS display: block;.

Check the below working code.

```
<body>
<div class="exp_article-header-bg">
    <div class="exp_article-header-inner">
        <h2 class="exp_article-header-title">TechnoVision 2017</h2>

        <div class="exp_article-header-author"></div>
        <div class="exp_article-header-lead"><p>TechnoVision 2017 gives you a framework to create a new digital story to
            solve problems and grasp new opportunities. Our 37 technology building blocks will help you to navigate the
            technology maze and give a clear direction to your business.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="exp_article-header-expand">
            **
            <div class="exp_link exp_link--white exp_link--expand">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="exp_link-label">EXPAND</button>
                **
                <span class="exp_button-arrow exp_button-arrow--down" id="expandDiv"
                      style="color: #000066; background-color: gainsboro;display: none;">I Got Expanded</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript function:-

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('expandDiv');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

check on plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/MWKYxmV6Jk2eId3Owt2u?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

where is ur form opening? if u're usingjquery,  just target the form id and do .submit()

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the 'onsubmit' event listener, most likely with a preveninstead of a click event.

```
document.querySelector("#submit-button").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    //your stuff here
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: Hey there, could you please include the JavaScript where you are adding the event listener? It looks like it's not in your original post. I set up a jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/ts5ycgm4/ , just fork it and we can start from there.